# Downloading files (not from repo) from private GitLab server

Tags: ssh, gitlab, authorization

I need to get a file from a private GitLab in a script (actually a Yocto recipe, if it matters).

Issuing: `https://gitlab2server.com/api/v4/projects/53/packages/generic/paCKAGE/21.08.16/FILE.tar.xz` on a browser works fine, but `wget <same URL>` fails with a "401 Unauthorized".

I can get around the problem with `curl --header "PRIVATE_TOKEN: xxxx" ...` but that means encoding my private token into a shell script which doesn't seem right.

To access a regular git repo I can use `git clone git:...` and it works because of the uploaded keys.

Using the equivalent `scp gitlab2server.com:/api/v4/... .` does not work because "Permission denied (publickey).".

What is the right way to do this?

Ideally I would need to have a `ssh` (actually `scp`, of course) access using pre-shared keys to access the files. I would hate to put large binaries into the git repo just to be able to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to authenticate with the GitLab API (including the Package API here) is using a personal access token, or the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` environment variable if running within GitLab CI/CD. `CI_JOB_TOKEN` is one of the [Predefined Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) available to every CI/CD Pipeline Job and holds a non-admin token.

Comment: I would have preferred to be able to use the preshared keys also for file download, but this works. It works only for CI/CD though, not from the command line :(

Comment: It would if you have an access token, but like you said it would either have to be hard coded  in the script or an environment variable.